# Unable to get jndi data source

Tags: java, tomcat

Unable to get jndi data source.
Error :

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/MyLocalDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]

Environment :  netbeans 8.0 + tomcat 8 + jdk8

1. In tomcat server at /conf/context.xml added below block:

   ```
   <Resource name="jdbc/MyLocalDB"
    global="jdbc/MyDB"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" auth="Container"/>
   ```
2. In tomcat server at /conf/server.xml added below block:

   ```
   <Resource name="jdbc/MyDB"
    global="jdbc/MyDB"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ARBADMIN"
    username="postgres"
    password="postgres"
    maxActive="100"
    maxIdle="20"
    minIdle="5"
    maxWait="10000"/>
   ```
3. Kept postgresql-9.3-1103.jdbc3  to tomcat /lib folder
4. Java code :

   ```
   ctx = new InitialContext();
   DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/MyLocalDB");
   con = ds.getConnection();
   stmt = con.createStatement();
   ```

In netbeans ide whether i need to do any thing?

Comment: Have you tried jdbc/MyDB?

Comment: yeah. getting error javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/MyDB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc]

Comment: Have you created a resource-ref entry in web.xml?
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyLocalDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref> Examples: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html